# Problems with install mysql 5.5.20 with homebrew

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-lion, homebrew

I installed homebrew and Xcode 4.3.2 with command line tools on Mac Osx Lion and when I now try to install mysql with :

```
brew install mysql -v
```

I get the error :

```
Error: #<BuildError: Failed executing: cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20 -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/var/mysql -DINSTALL_MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/share/man -DINSTALL_DOCDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/share/doc/mysql -DINSTALL_INFODIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/share/info -DINSTALL_MYSQLSHAREDIR=share/mysql -DWITH_SSL=yes -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci -DSYSCONFDIR=/usr/local/etc -DWITH_UNIT_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_READLINE=yes>
```

Here you find the full log :

https://gist.github.com/2421381

I checked the logs but there is nothing that can help me for the moment. Brew doctor is also clean and give no errors.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Me too. As of a few hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution with thanks to a reply of visoft on my gist post. This solution worked for me. The problem is coming from Cmake, I need version 2.8.7 instead of 2.8.8, run this code to get it work :

```
cd /usr/local
brew uninstall cmake
git checkout 948c2769 Library/Formula/cmake.rb
brew install mysql
```

After this, mysql was installed successfully.